# iOS - Figuring out which MKPointAnnotation was selected

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

So I have an NSArray of Dictionary objects containing a bunch of JSON data.  Using that data I populate a map with a bunch of MKPointAnnotations, each one representing the data in a given dictionary.  When a user taps on one of the annotation points, how can I figure out which point was tapped so that I can associate the correct data set with that point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your own annotation class so you can store additional information in each annotation. See my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15554322/341994

Notice the links provided there! My book discusses this in depth:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch34.html#_annotations

And you can download a working project that develops this notion:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/ch34p848map/p707p723map

Comment: How would I then get the instance of the class when the `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation` method is called?

Comment: You don't get the instance, you create it. - Look at the links I provided in the other answer. My book contains a complete discussion, and I provide downloadable projects that show you what to do.

Comment: Got it.  Took me a second to realize exactly how everything pieced together.  Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this delegate method will help you to do so.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"Tapped on: %@", view.annotation.title);
}
```

Also you can set tag on each annotation and check that inside the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate using `view.tag`.

Please refer [MKMapViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204) for more